# UITableViewCell position change while scroll UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My `UITableViewCell` position changed while scroll `UITableView`. Here i have more `UITableViewCell`. So it covers more than one page screen. When i scroll top to bottom the position of `UITableViewCell` is changed such like 1st cell went 5th. And 2nd cell came to 1st and etc.

My Code:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SignUpWithEmailCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    switch (indexPath.row) {

        case 0: {

            UILabel *lblFirstName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
            lblFirstName.text = @"First Name";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblFirstName];

            self.txtFirstName = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lblFirstName.frame.origin.x + lblFirstName.frame.size.width + 5, 0, 190, 40)];
            self.txtFirstName.delegate = self;
            self.txtFirstName.text = strFirstName;
            self.txtFirstName.tag = 0;
            self.txtFirstName.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            self.txtFirstName.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
            self.txtFirstName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            self.txtFirstName.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.txtFirstName];
            break;
        } case 1: {

            UILabel *lblLastName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
            lblLastName.text = @"Last Name";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblLastName];

            self.txtLastName = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lblLastName.frame.origin.x + lblLastName.frame.size.width + 5, 0, 190, 40)];
            self.txtLastName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            self.txtLastName.delegate = self;
            self.txtLastName.tag = 1;
            self.txtLastName.text = strLastName;
            self.txtFirstName.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            self.txtLastName.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            self.txtLastName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            self.txtLastName.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
            self.txtLastName.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.txtLastName];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}

 return cell;
}
```

Could anyone guide me to archive it correctly..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is you problem `if (cell == nil)` the first time that the cell is nil i make a cell then i try to reuse de cell the cell is no null so i add this cell like it was before, without make any changes, for resolve you problem you have to remove the `if` and for don't have leak is better that you make a custom cell with all the object in it.

Comment: I removed 'if (cell == nil)' loop. Now its working fine. But i have one doubt. Is UITableViewCell create continuously while scrolling ?? Will it show some memory warnings ??

Comment: yes every time you add al the item the you add with addSubview: over the last item, for that is better that you make a custom cell and you replace just the value of the objects

Comment: if you have to do 2 different type or cell you make 2 customCell and then you switch them, if is case 0 you make an return firstCustomCell else you make and return secondCustomCell

Answer (score 1):

You must set the visual elements of the cell even when cell is not nil. If you read the documentation, you will notice that Apple says that the cell's content must always be updated in this method. The reason is because checking for nil just tests if you must create a new cell. If you don't need to create a new cell, that means you are reusing a cell, and therefore it will most likely display contents from a row other than the one you intended. Therefore, you should reset the contents every time in this method.

From [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW11):

> The table view’s data source implementation of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should *always* reset all content when reusing a cell.

Here's some code to get you started... but it will need to be improved since you are adding subviews to the cells in this method. That should only happen when the cell is nil, and you should store a reference to those subviews so that they can be accessed at other times.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SignUpWithEmailCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    switch (indexPath.row) {

        case 0: {

            UILabel *lblFirstName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
            lblFirstName.text = @"First Name";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblFirstName]; // TODO: MUST BE MOVED

            self.txtFirstName = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lblFirstName.frame.origin.x + lblFirstName.frame.size.width + 5, 0, 190, 40)];
            self.txtFirstName.delegate = self;
            self.txtFirstName.text = strFirstName;
            self.txtFirstName.tag = 0;
            self.txtFirstName.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            self.txtFirstName.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
            self.txtFirstName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            self.txtFirstName.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.txtFirstName]; // TODO: MUST BE MOVED
            break;
        } case 1: {

            UILabel *lblLastName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
            lblLastName.text = @"Last Name";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblLastName]; // TODO: MUST BE MOVED

            self.txtLastName = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lblLastName.frame.origin.x + lblLastName.frame.size.width + 5, 0, 190, 40)];
            self.txtLastName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            self.txtLastName.delegate = self;
            self.txtLastName.tag = 1;
            self.txtLastName.text = strLastName;
            self.txtFirstName.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            self.txtLastName.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            self.txtLastName.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
            self.txtLastName.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
            self.txtLastName.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.txtLastName]; // TODO: MUST BE MOVED
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }


 return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To optimize the memory iOS initializes and uses only screen displayed cells. When you scroll to see next content it dequeues the non-visible cell and uses it for new visible cell. So, 1st cell is used at 8th row and so on. Now, in your code, you are not resetting the content when this dequeue operation is happening. All your cell content code is only when cell is not there. Take out the cell initializing code from your IF condition and you should be good to go.